# How to make a specific group by (window like function)

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

Bellow you can see the Table and context. 
I want to get 3 groups from the context in the table, so i want to group by `ABDC_IDENT` but when the `DATE_RANK` order breaks as you can see in the data after `DATE_RANK` 11 comes 1,2 (because it is the group B) then it continues to rank up for the group A (the order by is by `VARIOUS_DATES`).

What i want to get is 3 groups, the first is group A rank 1 to 11, the second group is B rank 1,2 and the third group should be the group A but ranks from 12 to 21. I hope this is clear for everyone.

Im currently experimenting with rows between *UNBOUNDED PRECEDING* and current row, any idea is welcomed, maybe it can be done in some other way also. Cheers and thx

Here is my fiddle, so you can build it easy for yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (ABDC_IDENT varchar(5), VARIOUS_DATES date, DATE_RANKS int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (ABDC_IDENT, VARIOUS_DATES, DATE_RANKS)
VALUES
    ('A', '31.12.2010', 1),
    ('A', '31.01.2011', 2),
    ('A', '28.02.2011', 3),
    ('A', '31.03.2011', 4),
    ('A', '29.04.2011', 5),
    ('A', '31.05.2011', 6),
    ('A', '30.06.2011', 7),
    ('A', '29.07.2011', 8),
    ('A', '31.08.2011', 9),
    ('A', '30.09.2011', 10),
    ('A', '31.10.2011', 11),
    ('B', '30.11.2011', 1),
    ('B', '30.12.2011', 2),
    ('A', '31.01.2012', 12),
    ('A', '29.02.2012', 13),
    ('A', '30.03.2012', 14),
    ('A', '30.04.2012', 15),
    ('A', '31.05.2012', 16),
    ('A', '29.06.2012', 17),
    ('A', '31.07.2012', 18),
    ('A', '31.08.2012', 19),
    ('A', '28.09.2012', 20),
    ('A', '31.10.2012', 21)
;
```

The desired result would be then inserted into another table

```
Table2

  GROUP_ABC |  MIN_DATE |  MAX_DATE  |
       A    |31.12.2010 | 31.10.2011 |
       B    |30.11.2011 | 30.12.2011 |
       C    |31.01.2012 | 31.10.2012 |
```

Comment: Can you show us the desire result in a table?

Comment: Does your version of Sybase support window functions?  There are so many versions of Sybase, and some do and some don't.  Also, why are you using backticks for the column names?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza i will do that asap.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff the fiddle site did that by itself, it generated the ddl's from text...it works there, so i didnt change it, my bad maybe

Comment: And to clarify furthermore, Sybase IQ v.15,4 ...i dont need it to be an window function...im only interested in the output at the end...i just thought a windowed function is the easiest/best solution

Comment: Why are you using character strings for dates?  That's going to be a nightmare to find the max and min for.  If you absolutely must use character strings, you should at least use yyyy-mm-dd format to make sorting much easier.

Comment: @Bacon Bits is the data type that important for 23 rows? Are you concerned performancewise or is something else bothering you? Pls elaborate

Comment: Strings are sorted alphanumerically, regardless of what they represent.  `SELECT GROUP_ABC, MIN(VARIOUS_DATES) GROUP BY GROUP_ABC` will return `'28.02.2011'` for group `'A'`.  That's correct, too, because for a string `'28.02.2011'` is less than `'31.12.2010'` because 2 has a lower value than 3.  You can't even easily convert the strings to dates because you have the single quotes around the values, so even if Sybase IQ knows how to convert `dd.mm.yyyy` strings to dates, you have to strip off the quotes to do it.

Comment: @Bacon Bits i have corrected my fiddle, hope it is more clear now. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use convert format 104 to handle the date strings.

Does this work?

```
select
    substring('ABCDEF', row_number() over (order by min(VARIOUS_DATES)), 1) as GROUP_ABC,
    min(VARIOUS_DATES) as MIN_DATE,
    max(VARIOUS_DATES) as MAX_DATE
from (
    select
        ABDC_IDENT,
        convert(date, VARIOUS_DATES, 104) as VARIOUS_DATES
        row_number() over (order by convert(date, VARIOUS_DATES, 104)) - DATE_RANKS as grp
    from Table1
) data
group by ABDC_IDENT, grp
```

or:

```
select
    substring('ABCDEF', row_number() over (order by MIN_DATE), 1) as GROUP_ABC,
    MIN_DATE, MAX_DATE
from (
    select
        ABDC_IDENT as GROUP_ABC,
        min(VARIOUS_DATES) as MIN_DATE,
        max(VARIOUS_DATES) as MAX_DATE
    from (
        select
            ABDC_IDENT,
            convert(date, VARIOUS_DATES, 104) as VARIOUS_DATES
            row_number()
                over (order by convert(date, VARIOUS_DATES, 104)) - DATE_RANKS as grp
    from Table1
    ) data
    group by ABDC_IDENT, grp
) t
```

Comment: You can ignore the convert date, i have edited the varchar to be date by default. ;)